# База данных исчезла, но файл temdb точно такого размера

Tags: sql, sql-server, резервное-копирование

При попытке включения MS SQL Server получаю ошибку 17051. Погуглив понял, что срок лицензии окончен, но у меня исчезла база данных. Толи из за этого, толи из за частого спонтанного выключения питания.
Последнему бекапу 100 лет в обед, но что я заметил- размер старых резервных копий до байта совпадает с файлом temdb.mdf 
Подскажите, как мне восстановить базу данных?